# Exported Java file don't open

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote a program in **Java** and exported it. If I try to open the *.jar* file **CMD** opens for and close immediately. How can I get it run?

Comment: How do you know it didn’t run? But you can open CMD yourself and run it from the command line.

Comment: How do you "open" the file? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Run the Jar from the command line as others have suggested. As long as the code does not catch then hide exception output, there should be a fat, juicy exception which details what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

try this command
    `java -jar your_program.jar`

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: Isn't this the exact answer needed (if there's a class with a `main` method inside)?

Comment: It doesn't work. And at the export in eclipse it shows, that there is a compile warning. And in CMD it says "Unable to access jar-file".

Comment: And if I open the jar directly it says that the mainclass couldn't get found.